# Backbone model creation | Conceptual understanding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can anyone explain how Models are created in Backbone? You pass in an object, but you are able to use new as if it were a function object.

This leads me to believe Backbone is somehow appending the object literal to a function object as you can not do `new {key1:value1, key2,value2}`

**Example from Backbone**

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.on('change:color', function(model, color) {
  $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});

sidebar.set({color: 'white'});

sidebar.promptColor();
```

Comment: on the backbonejs website, you can find the annotated source of backbone. Very instructive, quite easy enough to understand, and should answer your question !

Comment: well I already dissected the first 50 or so lines ( not - commented ) of Backbone...did not get that far in...plus a conceptual understanding before a concrete understanding is a better way to learn....question updated.  If I could read all 500 lines or so and understand it completely, I'd be some sort of JS god...

Comment: Start with [`extend`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1424) and go from there. The currently released version is a little different than the github version but that's of little consequence.

Comment: @mu...that link is cool...how can I get a similar link for jQuery?  I googled it and foung jQuery on github...but I could not find a similar code listing for jQuery once I got in github

Comment: jQuery is built from pieces so there isn't a single-file version in github.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with how the object system in JavaScript works and the concept of a [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) for an object and the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

If you define an object with some properties:

```
var myobj = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

And then try to do `new myobj` you'll get an error that `myobj` is not a function.

But, lets say we define a function that sets some passed in value to the `this` property:

```
var myobj = function(foo){
    this.foo = foo || "bar";
}
```

And lets try to make a `new` instance of that:

```
var m = new myobj()
m.foo
> bar
var m2 = new myobj('baz');
m2.foo
> baz
```

This works because functions in JavaScripts are just objects of type function:

```
typeof myobj
> "function"
typeof myobj.prototype
> "object"
```

Now, if you look at the [Backbone source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js) (specifically line 184) you'll see:

```
 var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
```

That line is saying that a model is actually a function that can accept two arguments, `attributes` and `options`.

This is what allows you to create a `new` copy of this.